# Delete row in Data Table aspx.net

Tags: asp.net

here i'm trying to delete row of data Table.I want to delete row where value in clicked index is equal to 0. I'm trying but it delete all data Table.Solution?

```
   protected void btnTest_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        DataTable dtCurrentTable = (DataTable)ViewState["Markici"];

        decimal noofcount = Convert.ToInt32(count); 

            var clickedRow = ((Button)sender).NamingContainer as GridViewRow;
            var clickedIndex = clickedRow.RowIndex;

            decimal old = dtCurrentTable.Rows[clickedIndex].Field<decimal>("Kolicina");
            //int oldValue = int.Parse(old); // in case that you don't know
            decimal newValue = old - 1; // just an example
            dtCurrentTable.Rows[clickedIndex].SetField("Kolicina", newValue.ToString());

      ////Here i'm trying to delete row of clicked button.
            if (old == 0)
            {
                for (int i = 0; i <= dtCurrentTable.Rows.Count; i++)
                {
                    dtCurrentTable.Rows[clickedIndex].Delete();

                    dtCurrentTable.AcceptChanges();
                    GridView2.DataSource = dtCurrentTable;
                    GridView2.DataBind();        
                }



            }
            //dtCurrentTable.Rows[clickedIndex]["Kolicina"] == "0";

            GridView2.DataSource = dtCurrentTable;
            GridView2.DataBind();                     

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Why are you even looping?

```
 if (old == 0)
{
    dtCurrentTable.Rows[clickedIndex].Delete();
    dtCurrentTable.AcceptChanges();
}
```